# Issue with ReactJS Keys

Tags: reactjs

I have some JSX that is giving me the error:
`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`
which I've run across before, but this time I can't see where the problem is. The markup is as follows:

```
    return isLoading ? (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="spinner"></div>
        <div className="App loading">
          <p><i>loading...</i></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    : hasError ? (
      <div className="App loading-error">
        &#x26A0; There is a network issue: Please try again later
      </div>
    )
    :
    (
      <div className="App" key={`op - ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 110)}`}>

        <>
        {shelves.map(s => {
          return (
           books[s].map((b,i) => {
            return (
                <>
                <h2>{((shelvesN.filter(o => o.value === s)))[0].label}</h2>
                <div key={`${s}-${i}`}>
                    <Link to={`/book/${b.id}`}>
                    <img src={b.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={b.title}></img>
                    </Link>
                    <Select className="sel-x"
                            placeholder="Choose a bookshelf..."
                            value={""}
                            options={shelvesN}
                            onChange={opt => changeShelf(opt.value,b.id)}
                    />
                </div>
                </>
            )
          })
          )
        })}
        </>
      </div>
    )
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way i see it, you are stuck here:

```
      <div className="App" key={`op - ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 110)}`}>
        <>
        {shelves.map(s => {
          return (
           books[s].map((b,i) => {
            return (
                <>
                <h2>{((shelvesN.filter(o => o.value === s)))[0].label}</h2>
                <div key={`${s}-${i}`}>
                    <Link to={`/book/${b.id}`}>
                    <img src={b.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={b.title}></img>
                    </Link>
                    <Select className="sel-x"
                            placeholder="Choose a bookshelf..."
                            value={""}
                            options={shelvesN}
                            onChange={opt => changeShelf(opt.value,b.id)}
                    />
                </div>
                </>
            )
          })
          )
        })
```

this block contains 2 maps, which returns lists.
the inner one shouldn't use <>, because it needs the key reference, so should the first one. something like:

```
shelves.map((s, I) => {
      return (
       <div key={I}>
       {books[s].map((b,i) => {
        return (
            <div key={`${I}-${i}`}>
            <h2>{((shelvesN.filter(o => o.value === s)))[0].label}</h2>
            <div >
                <Link to={`/book/${b.id}`}>
                <img src={b.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={b.title}></img>
                </Link>
                <Select className="sel-x"
                        placeholder="Choose a bookshelf..."
                        value={""}
                        options={shelvesN}
                        onChange={opt => changeShelf(opt.value,b.id)}
                />
            </div>
            </div>
            </>
        )
      })}
      </div>)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I still wound up playing parser to get it done but it was a lot easier with a second set of eyes, and welcome to SO!!

Answer (score 0):

You use iteration, which means you must use `keys`. [topic](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Your code looks awful and unreadable, you should work better on the style.

```
shelves.map((s, I) => {
      return (
       <div key={I}>
       {books[s].map((b,i) => {
        return (
            <div key={`${I}-${i}`}>
            <h2>{((shelvesN.filter(o => o.value === s)))[0].label}</h2>
            <div >
                <Link to={`/book/${b.id}`}>
                <img src={b.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={b.title}></img>
                </Link>
                <Select className="sel-x"
                        placeholder="Choose a bookshelf..."
                        value={""}
                        options={shelvesN}
                        onChange={opt => changeShelf(opt.value,b.id)}
                />
            </div>
            </div>
            </>
        )
      })}
      </div>)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `React.Fragment` from each array item, so assign the unique key to each Fragment, here:

```
books[s].map((b,i) => { return ( <> ..... </> )})
```

Use this code:

```
<div className="App" key={`op - ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 110)}`}>
    <>
        {shelves.map(s => {
            return (
                books[s].map((b,i) => {
                    return (

                        // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ add key here
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>

                            <h2>{((shelvesN.filter(o => o.value === s)))[0].label}</h2>
                            <div>
                                <Link to={`/book/${b.id}`}>
                                    <img src={b.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={b.title}></img>
                                </Link>
                                <Select className="sel-x"
                                    placeholder="Choose a bookshelf..."
                                    value={""}
                                    options={shelvesN}
                                    onChange={opt => changeShelf(opt.value,b.id)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })
            )
        })}
    </>
</div>
```